# Hashmap in c++ not ordering elements?

Tags: c++, hashmap

i have to study hash map implementation . i have studied that it will sort elements according to the order mentioned in template. Example Code is:

```
#include <hash_map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef pair <int, int> Int_Pair;

    hash_map <int, int>::iterator hmp1_Iter;

    hash_map <int, int , hash_compare <int, less<int> > > hmp1;                 
    hmp1.insert(Int_Pair(1, 13));
    hmp1.insert(Int_Pair(3, 51));
    hmp1.insert(Int_Pair(7, 22));
    hmp1.insert(Int_Pair(2, 31));

    cout<<"\nOperation1: hash_map<int, int, \nhash_compare<int, less<int> > > hmp1\n";
    cout<<"Operation2: hmp1.insert(Int_Pair(1, 13))...\n";
    cout<<"hmp1 data: ";
    for(hmp1_Iter = hmp1.begin(); hmp1_Iter != hmp1.end(); hmp1_Iter++)
    cout<<hmp1_Iter->first<<":"<<hmp1_Iter->second<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Expected Result of code is : 1:13  2:31 3:51 7:22
but it is giving 1:31 3:51 7:22 2:31 . But is should arrange key elements in ascending order.Pls explain why this is happening?

Comment: where did you sort tha hash map?

Comment: How do you expect a hash map to order elements? Hash maps store elements in "random" locations by definition. If you want sorted elements use a tree-based map, not a hash-based one.

Comment: @fatih_k the trait which we have mentioned hash_compare<int,less<int>> will order keys according to the template which we had given

Comment: @Damon bcoz we have given hash_compare<int , less<int>> this will sort elements which is the main advantage of hashing over sorting i.e greater efficiency . m i ryt??

Comment: @JasdeepSinghArora No, you're wrong. The key comparison is used simply to calculate the bucket that the value goes in - they're still unsorted.

Comment: Where did you get this `hash_map` from?

Comment: @juanchopanza Part of the [stdext](http://code.google.com/p/stdext/) namespace

Comment: @Yuushi yes ur answer is right , but pls have a look at http://www.tenouk.com/Module29a.html this output explained is wrong, i am not cleared with then for what purpose hash map is used?

Comment: @JasdeepSinghArora hash_map is intended for extremely fast insert/find/erase

Comment: @MerickOWA thanks for clearing my confusion .:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::hash_map` is an unordered associative container, which is usually implemented with hash tables (a hash of the key as an index in an array of linked lists)

If you need an "ordered hash map", you can use a `std::map`. It is usually a red-black tree and its key elements can be iterated in ascending order.

`std::hash_map` should be faster on insert and delete than a `std::map`.

Comment: "unordered binary search tree which is usually implemented with hash tables" makes no sense. There is nothing tree-like about the usual hash table implementation.

Comment: Yes, I guess a I kind of failed on my answer reorganization before posting

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN's website on the [hash_map Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d462wfh.aspx)

> The actual order of elements in the controlled sequence depends on the
>   hash function, the ordering function, and the current size of the hash
>   table stored in the container object. You cannot determine the current
>   size of the hash table, so you cannot in general predict the order of
>   elements in the controlled sequence.

Simply put, the order of the elements in a hash_map are never guaranteed to be in order, any cases in which they do appear to be in order is merely coincidence.

To make this even more clear, [the MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d462wfh.aspx) notes that

> This API is obsolete. The alternative is unordered_map Class.

Providing even more proof that hash_map is never intended to provide any order on its elements.